# C# Aspose BarCode QRCode low quality or small size

Tags: pdf, qr-code, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I have an issue with adding a QR-code to my pdf file.

If I use code like this (with `new Bitmap`), the resulting image quality is very low.

If use `barCodeBuilder.ImageQuality = ImageQualityMode.AntiAlias;` the quality is absolutely awful.

```
                    var barCodeBuilder = new BarCodeBuilder();

                    barCodeBuilder.CodeText = resultString;
                    barCodeBuilder.EncodeType = !qrCode ? EncodeTypes.Code128 : EncodeTypes.QR;

                    barCodeBuilder.AutoSize = false;
                    barCodeBuilder.Resolution = new Resolution(300, 300, ResolutionMode.Graphics);
                    barCodeBuilder.ImageHeight = 4000;
                    barCodeBuilder.ImageWidth = 4000;

                    // becomes even worse
                    //barCodeBuilder.ImageQuality = ImageQualityMode.AntiAlias;

                    var documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
                    documentBuilder.MoveToField(field, false);

                    documentBuilder.InsertImage(new Bitmap(barCodeBuilder.GetOnlyBarCodeImage(), !qrCode ? new Size(200, 30) : new Size(100, 100)));
```

If I use code without `new Bitmap`, the resulting image is extremely small.

```
                    var barCodeBuilder = new BarCodeBuilder();

                    barCodeBuilder.CodeText = resultString;
                    barCodeBuilder.EncodeType = !qrCode ? EncodeTypes.Code128 : EncodeTypes.QR;

                    barCodeBuilder.AutoSize = false;
                    barCodeBuilder.Resolution = new Resolution(300, 300, ResolutionMode.Graphics);
                    barCodeBuilder.ImageHeight = 4000;
                    barCodeBuilder.ImageWidth = 4000;

                    // becomes even worse
                    //barCodeBuilder.ImageQuality = ImageQualityMode.AntiAlias;

                    var documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
                    documentBuilder.MoveToField(field, false);

                    documentBuilder.InsertImage(barCodeBuilder.GetOnlyBarCodeImage());
```

Comment: Could you try saving the barcode image to disk and check if you get the same quality image. Also seeing your code segment, it seems you are using older version of Aspose.BarCode API, so kindly try using latest version (e.g Aspose.BarCode for .NET v20.3) with newer APIs.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I would suggest you to save the generated barcode as EMF metafile and then insert it in the word document. See BarCodeImageFormat.Emf https://apireference.aspose.com/net/barcode/aspose.barcode/barcodeimageformat. In this case barcode will be inserted as vector graphics and there will not be quality degradation.